# this.usuarioSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Usuario>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))); somebody know why this is wrong'

Tags: angular, typescript, function, rxjs

Im working angular 12.2.1, but i have a proble this dont recognize this line code, it supouse that is ok, but this mark a error on the LocalStorage.getItem say 'Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string''.

this.usuarioSubject.next(null);

and this i dont know why this too mark a error

somebody know how to solve or is my angular version

Comment: that error message tells you that types are not equal. You can't assign null to variable or function which expects string.

Comment: What is `Usuario`, could you please write its definition in your question?

Comment: it is interface      export interface Usuario{
    email: string;
    token :string,
}

Comment: yeah i know, that i cant assign, but im trying to remove the last user tha entered in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.usuarioSubject.next(''); Should do the trick. You cant set it to null but can set it to empty string which means empty user.

Comment: i couldnt do like exactly the same but you gave me an idea the parameter it shouldnt ampty or null, so i declared the value like empty, so thnk